# SQL group function is nested too deeply

Tags: sql, oracle, max

When I run the following SQL statement :

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ID_BARANG
               ID_CUST,
               MAX(JML) AS JML,
               TGL_TRANSAKSI
          FROM PEMBELIAN_DETIL_1301140002 
          NATURAL JOIN PEMBELIAN_1301140002 
          GROUP BY ID_TRANSAKSI
          ORDER BY MAX(JML) DESC
          )
  WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

I get following error :

> ERROR at line 4: ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply

can anybody help me ?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576338/sql-group-function-nested-too-deeply

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `MAX(JML) AS JML` and `ORDER BY MAX(JML) DESC`
The JML in the ORDER BY clause is not the original column JML, but the alias to the MAX(JML).
Therefore the ORDER BY expression is actually interpreted as `MAX(MAX(JML))`, which is nested group function.

---

In any case, this is a bad code.

- The columns selected in the aggregated subquery are invalid.
- The use of NATURAL JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT id_barang, 
               id_cust, 
               Max(jml) AS JML, 
               tgl_transaksi 
        FROM   pembelian_detil_1301140002 
               natural JOIN pembelian_1301140002 
        GROUP  BY id_transaksi, 
                  id_cust, 
                  tgl_transaksi 
        ORDER  BY jml DESC) 
WHERE  rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain why you made the changes you did so that OP can learn why you did what you did. Thanks. Also - did you mean `ID_BARANG` instead of `ID_TRANSAKSI`?